# Grouping distinct values

Tags: sql

Table with values:

```
Id  Val1  Val2
1   111    1
2   101    2
3          3
4   120    1
5   121
```

It has these constraints:

- `Val2` can have only three values (1,2,3).
- `Val1` can have many different values, including `null`, but but never 1,2, or 3.

I want to select distinct val1,val2 values with these exceptions:

1. If `Val1` is `null` and `Val2` is not 1, then I set `Val1` to `999`.
2. If `Val1` is `null`, and `Val2` is 1, then I set `Val1` to 999 and do not select `Val2`.
3. If `Val1 is not`null`, and`Val2`is 1, then I select`Val2`.

Result should be (if val1 have null value, and val2 have 1):

```
111
101
120
999 (null value set to 999)
121
2
3
```

Result should be (if val1 hasn't null value, and val2 have 1):

```
111
101
120
121
1
2
3
```

Result should be (if val1 has null value, and val2 has not 1):

```
111
101
999 (null value1 set to 999)
120
121
2
3
```

Comment: Maybe you should show what the resulting table would look like as well because that description of what you want is a mess.

Comment: @Coda17 has it, format an expected results table much like what you have w/ your values.  Include sql that you've tried and a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) never hurt either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select distinct coalesce(val, 999)
from ((select val1 as val from tablewithvalues) union all
      (select val2 from tablewithvalues)
     ) twv;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Coalesce, it will check if the value is null and replace with something else:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

For the check if the val1 or val2 should be used, use an IF:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

For example, the first step would be:

```
SELECT COALESCE(val1,999) from table1;
```